# Casting to unsigned without specifying a type

Tags: c, casting, unsigned, size-t

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  ssize_t a= -1;
  size_t b = (unsigned)a;
  return 0;
}
```

`a` is 8 bytes all set to `1`, however `b` becomes a 4 byte number when casted to `unsigned` without doing a proper `(unsigned size_t)`, why is that? why doesn't it turn into an 8 byte unsigned variable?

Comment: Why would you cast a negative value to `unsigned`?

Answer (score 5):

`unsigned` is short for writing `unsigned int`, so `unsigned` and `unsigned int` are the same type.

`unsigned size_t` does not exist; `size_t` is **already** unsigned.

> why doesn't it turn into an 8 byte unsigned variable?

Because `int`s are commonly 32 bit or 4 bytes.

If you want fixed width integers you can use `stdint.h` which defines `uint32_t`, `int32_t` etc.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know unsigned is short for writing unsigned int.

Comment: The same goes for `short` and `long`. `short = short int`, `long = long int`.

Answer (score 2):

The C standard sheds some light on this:

In § 6.7.2p2, Type specifiers, "- `unsigned`, or `unsigned int`" are in the same list entry, because they are equivalent type specifiers.

Answer (score 1):

As @marco-a told you that `unsigned` is shorthand for `unsigned int` and both are equivalent. The `sizeof(unsigned int)` could be 4 byte(commonly) or 8 byte, it's system-dependent. But `size_t` is an `unsigned integral data type` which is guaranteed to be big enough to contain the size of the biggest object the host system can handle. Basically the maximum permissible size is dependent on the compiler; if the compiler is **32 bit** then it is simply a typedef(i.e., alias) for `unsigned int` but if the compiler is **64 bit** then it would be a `typedef` for `unsigned long long`. The `size_t` data type is never negative.

Answer (score 0):

Casting a negative value to `unsigned` (independently of what type is the `unsigned`) is Undefined Behaviour.  You can cast only positive `signed` values to be `unsigned`.

The result of casting is not defined as a valid operation, and it depends on the architecture and the compiler implementation how it deals with that cast.

Anyway, when you add the `unsigned` keyword but don't specify the actual integer type you want, you have to think that `short`, `long`, `long long`, are also adjectives to the basic `int` type (which is the default type to substitute) so, to end, the default type is `int`.